# Which Flavour of Linux comes with default kernel 3.4?

Tags: linux, centos, linux-kernel

I was using centos but came to know it has restrictions to upgrade kernel version so looking for any other flavour with default 3.4 kernel version please suggest

Comment: http://distrowatch.com/

Comment: What does your application do where it requires x32abi?

Answer (score 1):

My fully-updated Fedora 16 box is currently running 3.4.11, and presumably F17 will be even newer (apparently, 3.6.9).  That said, these are in my opinion **unsuitable** for a server OS because of their very fast release cycle, frequent destabilising upgrades, and short support lifetime.

Sadly, it's those very properties that mean they're running a fairly cutting-edge kernel, which makes me wonder **why** you feel you need to be running such a recent kernel on a server (I'm assuming it's a server because you were looking at CentOS; if it's a desktop, that's different, try F17, it's great).

Comment: Yes its a server which you suggest for server with Kernal 3.4 version i want to use Kernal 3.4 version as it has x32abi were i need the performance of that abi for my app

Comment: Buy a bigger server.  Running a desktop distro on a server to save money is foolish, imho.